# Footer automaticly resizes css

Tags: html, css, width, footer

I have currently the following problem:
The footers width gets smaller as soon as i click on a product. Live example here:
(Small footer:)
http://osolemio.nl/serdar/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=97

(How it should be:)
http://osolemio.nl/serdar/index.php

I have tried several ways by editing the css, width 100% etc but nothing worked.
Someone see what is wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you working with? it seems like a div misplacing, are you doing this in plain html or using some sorta editor?

Comment: +1 for the `/* God I hate Microsoft! */` comment in the IE7 stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div id="content">` is not closed properly. It has to be closed before `<div id="footer">`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your footer  in the product page is getting rendered inside #content while in the main index page it's outside.

You have either forgotten to close any div or the code coming from CMS is screwing up your markup.

Answer (score 1):

In the product page there is one div which doesn't close (without `</div>`).
Find out it and add `</div>`. It's inside the `<div class="product-info">` element

Answer (score 0):

Take the `#footer` element out of the `#content` element and put it immediately *after* the `#content` element.